# Why does it l[i].pop(0) the second element of the sub-list and not the first

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list that is formated like this but much bigger.
I want to remove the numbers so i split the list and try to to pop the numbers by doing

```
L=['12345 xxxxx yyy','21354 xxxxx yyy','52135 xxxx yyy']
 
#split the list
List=[item.split(" ",1) for item in L]

print(L)
#[['12345', 'xxxxx yyy'], ['21354', 'xxxxx yyy'], ['52135', 'xxxx yyy']]

#pop numbers
L=[ L[L.index(i)].pop(0) for i in L]
```

I don't get why this removes the second part of each sub-list and not the first.

i can complete it without list-comprehensions but i am curious why this is happening
and i hope this isnt a dumb question.

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep everything but the numbers:

```py
#split the list
List=[item.split(" ",1)[1] for item in L]
```

Results:
`['xxxxx yyy', 'xxxxx yyy', 'xxxx yyy']`